# How to fix database update command error?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, ms-access-2007

I am making a project which can add, delete and edit data of users in a database.

I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition and for the database I am using Microsoft Access 2007-2013.

Okay, so basically my problem is with using the *'Add'* button and the *'Delete'* button and also the *'Save'* button, when I click the *'Add'* button I get this error:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

under the code: `dtaadpUser.Update(dtasetSB, "tbluser_data")`

full code for add button: http://gyazo.com/3239e0abb3288d693f604998a90b490c

And after searching a UserID or Surname in the search box and having a user shown and then clicking the *'Delete'* button I get this error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((UserID = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND First name IS NULL) OR (First name = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Surname IS NULL) OR (Surname = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Gender IS NULL) OR (Gender = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Type IS NULL) OR (Type = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND DOB IS NULL) OR (DOB = '.

under the code: `dtaadpUser.Update(dtasetSB, "tbluser_data")`

full code for delete button: http://gyazo.com/0114dbf615593fd1cc282cbbd3265371

And when I click the *'edit'* button and change one of the fields and then click *'Save'* I get this error:

> Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

under the code:  `dtaadpUser.Update(dtasetSB, "tbluser_data")`

I think that the problem is to do with the `.Update` command, but I may be wrong it's just what I think, either way I don't know how to solve the problem...

Comment: Please don't post your entire project source code. Ask a specific question and post only the relevent code, in the body of the question. If it's too much to post, then pare it down to an example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a field with a space inside. This will give problems in your update insert and delete query. 
You could try to resolve your problems using a OleDbCommandBuilder

```
Dim adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbluser_data", connection)
Dim builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
builder.QuotePrefix = "["
builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

This should be enough to force the adapter to use the OleDbCommandBuilder to create the appropriate command with the fields names enclosed in square brackets.

However this should to be tested with Access.....

Comment: When you build the adapter. The adapter should be kept global at the form level, so you could reuse the same instance when you need to execute the update command

Comment: The same error still appears.. Now I've changed all the fields in the database to have no spaces.. and it still doesn't work either